# css animation - make footer move up to down

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a footer as styled-components that move from down to up when the value is false.

I need that the footer will move up to down When the value is true (meaning hidden=true).

how can I execute that? I tried useEffect but it gives me an error.

my styled-components:

```
const StyleCard = styled.div`
  animation: nav-load 500ms ease;

  @keyframes nav-load {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
`;
function App() {
  const [footer, setFooter] = useState(true);

  return (
    <APPDIV>
      <Navbar />
      <Button onClick={() => setFooter(!footer)} variant="primary">
        Primary
      </Button>{" "}
      <Main />
      <StyleCard hidden={footer}>
        <Card.Header>Quote</Card.Header>
        <Card.Body>
          <blockquote className="blockquote mb-0">
            <p>
              {" "}
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
              posuere erat a ante.{" "}
            </p>
            <footer className="blockquote-footer">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </footer>
          </blockquote>
        </Card.Body>
      </StyleCard>
    </APPDIV>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: are you looking for help with styling or just the conditional rendering?

Comment: hey, I need to know how to change the style in conditional rendering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of using `animation` just use conditional css rendering that styled components supports base on passed props:

```
  transform: ${(props) => (props.show ? "translateY(0)" : "translateY(100%)")};
  transition: transform 500ms;
```

[this is a working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styledcomponent-iuekq?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to animate the footer in a different location or are you essentially hoping that the footer becomes the nav bar depending on this condition?

Since you're using styled components you can write JavaScript within your components easily.. you could just change the style depending on the condition.

(Sorry don't have enough rep for a comment)

Comment: I just want to move to footer down when the boolean equal true